# Не получается запустить сервер в Atom

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, сервер

Не получается запустить сервер в Atom, при том, что в консоли (командной строке) запуск проходит успешно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дублирую текстом:
cmd:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd /D d:/

d:\>python -m venv my_venv_name

d:\>my_venv_name\Scripts\activate

(my_venv_name) d:\>cd Scripts
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.

(my_venv_name) d:\>pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.2.10
  Using cached asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Installing collected packages: asgiref, sqlparse, pytz, django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.3.1 django-3.1.7 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'd:\my_venv_name\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(my_venv_name) d:\>d:\my_venv_name\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1

(my_venv_name) d:\>django-admin startproject mysite

(my_venv_name) d:\>cd D:\my_venv_name\Scripts

(my_venv_name) D:\my_venv_name\Scripts>django-admin startproject mysite

(my_venv_name) D:\my_venv_name\Scripts>cd mysite

(my_venv_name) D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite> manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 23, 2021 - 12:55:15
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

(my_venv_name) D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite>python manage.py startapp main

(my_venv_name) D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 23, 2021 - 17:57:44
Django version 3.1.7, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Atom:

```
    PS D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite> django-admin manager.py runserver
django-admin : Имя "django-admin" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие
 и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ django-admin manager.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite> python django-admin manager.py runserver
C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite\django-admin': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite> python manager runserver
C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite\manager': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite> python manager.py runserver

C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite\manager.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS D:\my_venv_name\Scripts\mysite>
```

После активации виртуальной среды:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во втором скрине, вероятно, дело было в опечатке. Но, даже после исправления, корректно запустить сервер не удаётся (скрин 4) // django установлено, а активация виртуальной среды происходит прям на 4 скрине, но всё равно не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIQXA.png]
Попробовал запустить в PyCharm Community, получилось вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Явно забыли активировать venv

Comment: @andreymal, попробовал (3 скрин), не помогло

Comment: нашёл проблему, которая была во втором скрине, но запустить сервер мне так и не удалось

Comment: также при запуске сервера через консоль, запускается лишь стартовая страница, без тех изменений, которые я ввёл в программе

Comment: Вы не активировали окружение

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл проблему
Нужно было указать путь к `Django` в `Path`

Для тех, кто не знает как это делается:
Нажимаете на подчёркнутую строку, затем на Path -> Изменить -> Создать -> Прописываете путь -> OK

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]